# Difference between "I am" and "I'm" for the feeling and punctuation

Tags: meaning, differences, punctuation

We all know *I am* and *I'm* are same but recently I figure out there is a bit difference.

When we said *I'm a programmer*, the feeling is like just normal telling other, but while you said *I am a programmer* it feels more like I'm proud to be a programmer, although is you said hardly *I'm a programmer* it'll still get the feel, but I think the *I am* one got more feeling.

Am I correct for the thought? Does *I am* and *I'm* really makes others feel different?

Comment: Definitely depends on the context. I suppose in normal casual conversation you'd normally use `I'm`, so by actually taking time to say `I am`, you're consciously making the effort to emphasise the statement, which might be interpreted as you stated.

Comment: If you're talking about the words alone, there is no difference.

If you're talking about tone of voice, there could be all the difference in the world… and still, the spelling would hardly be relevant.

Comment: If it's in writing "I am" would be formal, where as "I'm" is informal, therefore "I am" might appear more professional and consequently insinuate to the reader you take pride in being a programmer.  If you're talking about the tone of voice,  your intonation will make worlds of difference...

Comment: 'I am a programmer' if not used to generate a special effect (such as emphasis to underline the fact, correct a misapprehension ...) sounds robotic, almost self-deprecating with this particular example. The contracted form is almost universally used in conversation. / You may find the sister site, ELL, more suitable, Andrew. 'Does using _I am_  in place of  _I'm_ really create a different impression on hearers?'